# Using Checkboxes on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox

I have a Google sheet (Main) with a lot of data. I want to import data from Main sheet to another sheet (A) using Checkboxes (or any other filtering method).

Once the data is imported to sheet (A), I want to be able to make changes to it and those changes should reflect in the Main data/sheet.

Can this be done? Please help/advise.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have two different sheets, the best available options is to utilize the `IMPORTRANGE`feature from Sheets.

It would allow you to import the data from the main Sheet by adding the URL and then adding the range of the Sheet.

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")
```

Example and information can be found under [this article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

This would be the best filter, I am not sure it would be possible using checkboxes unless you script it.